# How to make Graphics3D object with different colors

Tags: graphics

Here is a sample `Graphics3D` object:

```
gr1 = Graphics3D[
  GeometricTransformation[
   {Red, Sphere[]}, 
   Table[TranslationTransform[{i, 0, 0}], {i, 10}]
  ]
]
```

[image]

How do I apply different colors (or other directives) when using `GeometricTransformation`?

I get something like the following effect

```
gr2 = Graphics3D[
  GeometricTransformation[{RGBColor @@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3}], Sphere[]}, #] & /@ 
  Table[TranslationTransform[{i, 0, 0}], {i, 10}]
]
```

[image]

So, how to change `gr1` to `gr2`?

`Normal@gr1[[1]]` does not change it to many spheres.

Comment: Please ***do not*** use block quotes for code, instead indent each line in the code block by 4 spaces. To format inline code surround it by grave (`) symbols. ***Do not*** use $\LaTeX$ to mark up code. As you have been here a good while, I will let you reformat the last code block.

Comment: @rcollyer well, I just learn to use that @@ mark-down, I'wll edit it.

Comment: one reason why I use block quotes is sometimes 4 spaces only take effect in the first line.

Comment: @HyperGroups Well, every line requires it if it belongs in the code block. But, if you use the Code Sample button (or shortcut), you need to select _all_ of the code as it only moves the text you've selected.

Comment: btw, you can find some editing help here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: @rcollyer Can I use `<blackquote><pre>` instead of `<` and `four spaces` each line?

Comment: @rm-rf Can I use `<blockquote><pre>` instead of `<` and `four spaces` each line?

Comment: Please **don't** use blockquote. You can use `<pre><code>` though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
gr1 /. gt_GeometricTransformation :> 
   Map[GeometricTransformation[First[gt], #] &, 
    Last[gt]] /. {_RGBColor :> RGBColor @@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3]}
```

[image: Colored spheres]

*Edit:* Alternative way:

```
gr1 /. gt_GeometricTransformation :> Thread[gt, List, -1] /.
 {_RGBColor :> RGBColor @@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3]}
```

*Edit 2:*
To convert `GeometricTransformation[..]` to graphics primitives and directives:

```
gr1 /. gt_GeometricTransformation :> 
   Map[Normal @ GeometricTransformation[First[gt], #] &, 
       Last[gt]] /. {_RGBColor :> RGBColor @@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3]}
```

Comment: nice+1, can we normal the `gr1` to `Graphics3D[]` without `GeometricTransformation`?

Comment: @HyperGroups `gr1` is already `Graphics3D`.  I think you're asking for a function like `Normal` to turn a `GeometricTransformation` of a list into a list of `GeometricTransformation`s.  I don't think there is a built-in function to do that, and you would have to use something like `Map` the way I did.

Comment: I mean In `gr1`, we still have `GeometricTransformation` in the `FullForm` list. But not convert one sphere to 5 spheres each with new coordinates.

Comment: Ah, I see. Take `Normal` of the `GeometricTransformation[..]` -- see the edit.